# Converting/Mapping between objects/DTO's and Entity or vice versa that require a call to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, mapping, refactoring

We have an integration system. We are converting/mapping one object returned by an API to another different object to be used in POST request of another totally separate API. Right now, everything is done in one giant function making debugging really time consuming.

However, it is not as simple as using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) or a simple custom mapping class. The conversion requires lot of calls in between. A simplified version for example:
Let say following is the JSON returned by a GET API call at url (http://example.com/getCustomer)

```
{
    id:1,
    addressId:42
    countryid:333,
    stateId:666
}
```

Now, we want to convert this to another object that can be sent in a POST request call to a different API say (http://foo.org/createPatron)

```
{
    name:ABC,
    address:123 Random Street
    country:Canada
    state:Ontario
    customerSince: 4/8/2018
    customerType: VIP
}
```

So this conversion requires lots of other API calls in addition to other logic to build right kind of object.

Now, I am in dilemma to where this conversion responsibility should take place.
I have a POCO from one call and POCO from another call. Any design patterns here? Should an api caller object be passed to POCO's so that API calls can be made from it?

**

### EDIT 1: Expanding on the problem a bit more and in another way.

Consider this way: I have this DTO

```
// assume getters and setters
class UserDTO {
  long id;
  int countryCode;
  int stateCode;
}
```

Now I want to convert this to following entity

```
// assume getters and setters
class User {
  long id;
  string countryName;
  string stateName;
}
```

However, to convert *countryCode* in  *UserDTO* to *countryName* in *User* in need to make a call to get all country code to countryName mappings like: http://example.org/getCountryList. After getting this list I have to find the name of the country with the code in DTO. Then have to do same thing for state as well.

As you can imaging this with numerous other properties. Some of which may require some validation and combination before assignment in User.

So I am dependent on other data sources to convert *UserDTO* to *User*. Again, where should this responsibility be handled? One way something like(Note we could use constructor and all that but that is not the point):

```
// assume getters and setters
class User {
  long id;
  string countryName;
  string stateName;

   public UserDTO FromUserDTO(ApiCaller apiCallerm,UserDTO userDTO){
       var countries = apiCaller.GetCountryList();
       this.countryName = countries.First(c => c.countryCode.Equals(userDTO.countryCode));
 .
 .
 .
```

Now the problem here is that ApiCaller is being passed to Entity or it could be passed to DTO which will in a way violating Single Responsibility principle.

So again my question is: where this conversion responsibility should take place?

Comment: Honestly, your post can be "unclear" and "too broad". Nobody can guess for you...what is "too complex"? You (seem to) state that you are _dependent_ on other sources of data - so, what are your realistic options? You're asking for _guesses_ to come up with some "architecture"?

Comment: This converter pattern may help you - https://ramesh-java-design-patterns.blogspot.in/2018/03/converter-pattern.html

Comment: @EdSF My apologies if that was not clear to you. I have edited the comment and expanded on it. Please let me know if its clear now or not. Thanks